CI Pipeline Trivy config scan not outputting report?
I'm using Trivy to scan helm charts for misconfiguration issues. Both on my local and in Gitlab CI the following command is not writing the report.json file to disk. What am I missing? :/
docker run -v $(pwd):/app aquasec/trivy:latest --severity MEDIUM,HIGH,CRITICAL --output report.json --format json config  /app

The command itself without the output parameter runs just fine and gives me the results I need

That looks like the output file is being written into the container-temporary filesystem.  A container can't normally access the host filesystem.

Ah, correct, I should have specified /app/report.json instead of just report.json. I assumed the process would execute in the current /app dir but it doesnt.
